# Save data as Arrays in Mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays

I am trying to make a Quiz Game. I am having the table `Questions`  in MySQL

```
Columns -> id,
           Question
           Option_A
           Option_B
           Option_C
           Option_D
           Answer
```

Here I am having a definite number of options. But I want to have dynamically many options for each Question.
Can I save the options as an array in MySQL, if we can please help me out with this problem

Comment: It sounds like what you'd have is a separate table for the options, which has a foreign key back to the question.  Is that not the case here?  What are you trying and what isn't working?

Comment: MySQL has no concept of an Array I am afraid, you need to create a child table linked to the parent with the id of the parent. Then you can have 1 or a million child options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Concept of Array In MySQL. Create a Table `QuestionOptions` which has foreign key `FK_Qusetion` Refrenced By  `Question_ID` in Question Table.Then you Can Add Many Questions Against A Single Question Thanks